# how to set default value for select 2 dropdown using angularjs json data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, forms, grails

> I am using grails select dropdown element. I need to set default value for select2 dropdown options while click
>   edit option in a form using angularjs..when i click edit button, then
>   i have fetch related data for that form and update to form fields
>   value as json object..Now normal text fields has been updated
>   successfully.but select-2 dropdown fields doesn't updated to current value as
>   selected.What's wrong with my code..here i have set common name for form model and object key like object key name and ng-model name are same for all datas..

Thanks advanced..

**My Object for update to form fields:**

```
Object {id: 3, name: "uday", code: "1", moveTaskType: "SPOT", priority: 1…}
```

**My Form select2 Code:**

```
 <g:select id="moveTaskType" name="moveTaskType" from="${com.aa.fsight.MoveTaskRuleDef.MoveTaskType.class.getEnumConstants().collect{[name:it.name(), type: it.type]}}" optionKey="name" optionValue="type" class="select2 multiSelect" noSelection="['':'None']" ng-model="taskCreateForm.moveTaskType" />
```

**My Controller code for data updation:**

```
$scope.taskCreateForm=data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use the select of angularjs ? You can bind the property directly with your tabs and choose your default selection.

Comment: angualrjs have using now just migrate to angularjs..not pure angularjs..application has grails, with angularjs..so select option has used for some multi purpose..now i don;t like to change grails select option to angularjs select..i need to change like above code wise..